# My Portugal visa was revoked after my appeal application had been approved

Tags: indian-citizens, portugal, visa-refusal-appeal

I was applying Portugal Schengen visa, which was refused by Delhi Portugal Embassy. After that I appealed my visa application on 3rd August, this appeal has been approved on 18th August, also I have received Approval Email from Embassy. But at the end of the movement my visa has been revoked, but I don't know why? In this situation what can I do as the next steps? Anyone know more about like this my case ?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post the revocation letter/email, with personal details blanked.

Comment: It would be useful as well to see the letter or email declaring the approval of the appeal.

Comment: Does this mean that the *appeal* request was approved, which then asserted the original decision? Please post the detail: why the visa was refused, (the rejection letter), the "appeal approval" email, what additional information you provided for the appeal, and the final reply.